# Does "OFFSET" in Oracle reads all data from first?

Tags: oracle, limit, offset

I know that `OFFSET 10000 LIMIT 20` in Mysql reads all data from first to 10020, and discards first 10000 data.
Does `OFFSET 10000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY` in Oracle work the same?

Answer (score 0):

No, but of course it must read the proportionate of rows to satisfy the ordering sequence,

eg

```
select * from emp
order by empno
```

reads every row so they can be sorted, and

```
select * from emp
where deptno = 10
order by empno
```

reads every row for department of 10 and then can sort them.

(There's a few special cases where we can skip that with indexes etc, but that's a separate discussion).

Coming back to FETCH FIRST / OFFSET, in effect we are amending the query to satisfy that need:

```
select ...
from   mytable
order by col
offset 100 fetch 20
```

becomes

```
select ..., row_number() over ( order by col) as r
from mytable
```

because then we can do

```
select 
from ( select ..., row_number() over ( order by col) as r
     from mytable
)
where r between 100 and 120
```

to match your FETCH/OFFSET needs.